# Add Text or Label to a Silverlight Arc

Tags: silverlight

Hi would it be possible to text or label to an Shape object in silverlight like an arc? Currently I created a chart compose of multiple arcs, I need to set a label on top of the arc to identify whose data it is.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a PathListBox if you want to place the text on an arc. See [text along curvature path like circular or arc in silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484118/text-along-curvature-path-like-circular-or-arc-in-silverlight)

Alternatively, you can position your own TextBlock object. Use the Polar to Rectangular conversion http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/coordinates/polar_-_rectangular_conversion.htm

For instance if the center of your circle is 10,20 and the radius is 30 and the angle where you want to place the textblock is 45, then

```
double DegreeToRadian(double degree) { return Math.PI / 180 * degree; }
x = 30 * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(45)) + 10
y = 30 * Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(45)) + 20
```

Comment: Thanks we used the Polar to Rectangular conversion :)